# Тернарный оператор в примерах в книге Шилдта

Tags: c#

Не первый раз вижу,что в книге шилдта написано:

```
int max = x < y ? x : y;
```

Я так понимаю, это значит, что если `х` меньше `y` - выводим `x`, иначе `y`. Тогда почему он называет переменную `max`? Это опечатка или я неправильно понимаю конструкцию?

Comment: Шилдт — очень неаккуратный автор. Плюс возможно ошибка перевода. Верьте своим глазам, а не тому, что он пишет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вы вырвали строчку из контекста. Дальше по коду эта переменная используется в условии цикла именно как максимум:

```
/* Determine if x and v have a common divisor. 
    If so, return least and greatest common factors in
    the out parameters. */

public bool HasComFactor(int x, int y, out int least, out int greatest)
{
    int i;
    int max = x < y ? x : y;
    bool first = true;

    least = 1;
    greatest = 1;

    // Find least and greatest common factors.
    for (i = 2; i <= max / 2 + 1; i++)
    {
        if (((y % i) == 0) & ((x % i) == 0))
        {
            if (first)
            {
                least = i;
                first = false;
            }
            greatest = i;
        }

    }

    if (least != 1) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Собственно обычно и принято именовать переменные соответственно тому как они используются, а не тому как их инициализируют.

Comment: На самом деле читается, как вынос мозга.

Comment: я только не понимаю, почему тогда в ней минимальное из двух значений,если она используется как максимум?

Comment: @Timothy, ну, она как граница в цикле используется. В этом смысле действительно max. Вы не зацикливайтесь на этом, вам же сам язык важно изучить.

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Данное выражение можно записать как:

```
if(x < y)
{
  max = x;
}
else
{
  max = y;
}
```

По логике мы нашли min. 
Такой вид записи очень популярен и удобен, 8 строчек кода мы заменяем одной.

Answer (score 0):

Тут говориться что вы как программист на N строке создаете переменную max типа int и инициализируете ее возвращаемым значением тернарного оператора у которого условие X меньше Y, если условие выполняется возвращаться левая часть после оператора "?" если нет то правая. Ну а насчет того что писал Шилд это нужно смотреть в контексте самого кода его программы.

К слову, использование тернарного оператора плохая практика так как затрудняет читаемость кода, ну а если мы хотим быть хорошими программистами то мы должны писать код который будет понятен другим людям сопровождающим этот код после вас, единственный случай когда можно использовать тернарный оператор это очень простые выражения, как в вашем примере)))

Comment: > плохая практика -- весьма спорное утверждение. Для простых выражений -- очень даже хорошая. Потому как код должен быть не только простым, но и по возможности кратким. Может быть вы и оператором ?? никогда не пользуетесь?

Comment: а вы дочитали до конца что я написал? Я сказа о том что тернарные оператор можно использовать в простых выражениях ... но только в простых.